# frequency sorting problem python - sorted() does not give what I would expect

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, frequency

I have code like this:

```
def frequency_sorting(numbers):
    return sorted(numbers, key=lambda i:numbers.count(i),reverse=True)
```

Alternatively:

```
def frequency_sorting(numbers):
    return sorted(numbers, key=numbers.count,reverse=True)
```

When I call:

```
frequency_sorting([3,4,11,13,11,4,4,7,3])
```

Both give me:

```
[4, 4, 4, 3, 11, 11, 3, 13, 7]
```

I would expect:

```
[4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 11, 11, 13, 7]
```

I know how to solve the initial idea. I just need to understand in theory why my code does not work.

Comment: `3` and `11` have the same count, and that's the only sorting key you use. Your expected output seems to show that you want to use a second key, but you didn't make it explicit. Why  3s before 11s?

Comment: Because that was the initial order. The result my code gives does not sort 3 by frequency at all. Why?

Comment: I know '''sorted(numbers, key=lambda i:(numbers.count(i),-i),reverse=True)''' solves this code, I don't understand why you would use '-i' there and why it should help.

Comment: It's the second key to be considered when first key is same, i.e. number count is same. Since you have used `reverse=True`, you should sort by `-i` for numbers with same count to be sorted in ascending order.

Comment: ok, but why did the code ignored the first key with 3? It results with '''[4, 4, 4, 3, 11, 11, 3, 13, 7]'''.

Comment: Using `-i` as second key does not return the expected result!! Instead, it returns `[4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 11, 11, 7, 13]`. Instead you should use the index of the number, see my answer.

Comment: @KamalValikhanov  3s before 11s  was not the original order.  They appear in the original list in this order: 3, 11, 11 then 3. So, as sort in Python is guaranteed to be stable, this is the order that is kept in the sorted list. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work because both 11 and 3 (in your example) have the same count; the same priority for sorting.

So `3, 11` is an ordered sequence just like `11, 3` or `3, 3, 11, 11` or `3, 11, 3, 11` so are all correct and the choice is made by how the algorithm is implemented.

So you need to specify that the key of the order is not only the number of equal elements, but the the number of equal elements (with higher importance) and the element itself (if you want this). So if you want a reverse order for number of equal elements and (then) an order for the elements value you could just use:

`sorted(numbers, key=lambda i:(-numbers.count(i),i))`

or equally

`sorted(numbers, key=lambda i:(numbers.count(i),-i),reverse=True)`

You could want the order to be by number of elements and (then) first appearance of the element, in this case you can use:

`sorted(numbers, key=lambda i:(-numbers.count(i),numbers.index(i)))`

Or you can use something else; it depends on how you want to sort elements with same count but different value

Comment: This does not return the expected result: `[4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 11, 11, 7, 13]` (7 and 13 are reversed)

Comment: @RiccardoBucco True, but it seems to me that the question is about the fact that 11 and 3 are mixed; then I don't know how he wants the other values, it depends. But thanks, I updated the answer to specify it

Answer (score 2):

Sorts are [guaranteed to be stable](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts), which means that if some items have the same key value, their original order is retained.

It is easier to see what is happening with strings and no reverse order:

```
list(sorted(['zzz', 'aa', 'cc', 'bb', 'bbb', 'aaa'], key=len))
# ['aa', 'cc', 'bb', 'zzz', 'bbb', 'aaa']
```

All strings of length 2 come first, in their original order, then all strings of length 3, also in their original order.

In your code, the values with count 2 are, in this order, 3, 11, 11 and 3. So, they will stay in this order after the sort (reversed, as you asked for it, but that will look the same).

If you want to sort by count, then by value (and not by original order), you have to make it explicit, with:

```
def frequency_sorting(numbers):
    return sorted(numbers, key=lambda i:(numbers.count(i), -i), reverse=True)
```